# Java method with parameterized list type parameter

Tags: java, generics

Let's say we have two classes Parent and Child:

```
public class Parent {
}

public class Child extends Parent {
}
```

And we have method with following argument:

```
public void foo(List<Parent> list) {
...
}
```

My question why is following method arguments is illegal(case A)

```
List<Child> list = List.of(new Child());
foo(list); //compile error
```

but at the same time such case is valid(case B)

```
foo(List.of(new Child());
```

`List.of()` has such signature `static <E> List<E> of(E... elements)`, so i expect that
`List.of(new Child())` has type `List<Child>` and because of [this wildcard rule](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html)(`List<Child>` not extends `List<Parent>`) i think that both cases must not compile.

But why case B compiles? Compiler sees, that `List.of(new Child())` doesn't have explicit type and checks that every item of list can be casted to `Parent.class` and do it to obtain correct type?

Comment: just do this instead of case B:         List<Parent> plist = List.of(new Child()); foo(plist);  See what happens? The same as in your case B - but explicitly. While your case A sets the type of the list to sth. different.  BTW. you don't have a function but rather a method foo.

Comment: change your method signature to `foo(List<? extends Parent> list)` to accept descendants of Parent.

Comment: @juwil just as i thought, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java generics are invariant. `List<Child>` is not a subtype of `List<Parent>`.

In the second case, the parameter of `foo()` requires type `List<Parent>`, which forces `List.of()` to be inferred with `E` being `Parent` (i.e. `List.<Parent>of(new Child())`). Notice that `new Child()` can be passed to `List.<Parent>of()` since `Child` is a subtype of `Parent`.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```java
List<Parent> list = List.of(new Child());
foo(list);
```

You can assign a list of subtypes to a variable declared as a list of types.

You can not pass a list of types to a method declared to accept a list of subtypes.